# .toggleClass not working?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm trying to get a footer class to display when a minimized nav sidebar is expanded by using Jquery and bootstrap visible/hidden classes. The toggle function works on two other elements and another with the same ID (!), just not the footer class with the id '#filler' :S

Staging [shrink screen below 768px width to see issue]: http://themidastouch.github.io/greenroom/

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){/* off-canvas sidebar toggle */

$('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
$(this).toggleClass('visible-xs text-center');
$(this).find('i').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-right glyphicon-chevron-left');
$('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
$('#lg-menu').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
$('#xs-menu').toggleClass('visible-xs').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
$('#filler').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
$('#btnShow').toggle();
});
});
```

HTML:

```
                <ul class="nav hidden-xs" id="lg-menu">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#" class="three-d">
                            <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i>Home</span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i>Home</span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i>Home</span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="three-d">
                                                    <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i>Blog</span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i>Blog</span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i>Blog</span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="three-d">
                            <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i>Contact</span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i>Contact</span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i>Contact</span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <footer class="text-center hidden-xs" id="filler">
                    <ul class="social">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-lg "></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg "></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-lg "></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-square fa-lg "></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    &copy; Greenroom 2015</footer>

                <!-- tiny only nav-->
                <ul class="nav visible-xs" id="xs-menu">
                    <li><a href="#" class="three-d text-center">
                            <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-home fa-sm"></i></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="three-d text-center">
                                                    <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o fa-sm"></i></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="three-d text-center">
                            <span style="color: #27ae60;"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="three-d-box">
        <span class="front"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i></span>
                            <span class="back"><i class="fa fa-info fa-sm"></i></span>
                            </span>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your id for your footer from filler to footer.  Then make sure to change it in your js also.  `<footer class="text-center hidden-xs" id="footer">`

```
$('#footer').toggleClass('hidden-xs').toggleClass('visible-xs');
```

Pretty sure this is what you're trying to achieve.  Check out my fiddle to see
http://jsfiddle.net/a4mqw9ox/

You'll still have to have your js for your filler id as well though

Comment: I can't believe this worked :/ what the f@#$@#?? Does this mean that the js only worked for one element with the #filler id? 

So angry at js right now.

Comment: Don't get me started with js and redundancy issues :)  Glad it worked for you.

Comment: the HTML in the question only shows one `#filler`.  it's an `id`.  it's supposed to be unique.  you shouldn't have more than one element with a given `id`.  if you want multiple elements with the same `id`, use `class` instead.